# What is the "compression ratio" of air hitting the nose?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag, aircraft-physics

Sorry but I don't know how to accurately phrase this question. I want to know how much compression results from air hitting the nose of an aircraft.

I'm interested in the traditional airliners (Mach 0.85, blunt nose, like B747 or A320), as well as the supersonic stuff like Concorde and even Mig-31.

Is there an equation for this? Presumably with cross section area and some kind of coefficient of form drag. I'm looking for a density and/or pressure change.

I want to know if this is significant, like if the aircraft actually has to do a lot of extra work to overcome the greater density in the nose air. But there are actually several reasons. I want to calculate how much heat arises from the adiabatic compression, which will let me know if some kind of active cooling is required for a given material. I want to know if the increased density of the nose air actually changes the general drag equation, like if you have to put in a higher density value when just calculating the fuselage drag. I want to know what possible boost you can get from the "ram effect" such as from a ramjet.

In this question, all I'm really asking for is the compression ratio...or change in density, or change in pressure...sorry I don't know which one is more accurate. If I just have that, then I think I can answer the rest using other equations I know of.

I wanted to explain myself in case this appears too broad or too xyz thing, sorry can't remember that term either. Hopefully someone will know an equation that can answer this. Equations give hard numbers, so they're always better than relative adjectives like "larger", "negligable", etc.

Also, if someone can suggest tags, please do so. Couldn't think of anything better than "drag".

Comment: The pressure on the nose (or in the pitot) is called total pressure, and includes pressure due to velocity and static pressure. The compression ratio is the ratio between this total pressure and the static pressure. Subsonic and supersonic velocities have different effects. See [this document](http://mae-nas.eng.usu.edu/MAE_5420_Web/section5/section.5.5.pdf) which is quite complete.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you seek is called the *stagnation pressure*, which is the pressure rise experienced in a given parcel of air if all the kinetic energy associated with that parcel's velocity were to be converted without losses into potential energy (stored work) of compression according to the ideal gas law. The equation for stagnation pressure is

$$ \frac{P_\text{stagnation}}{P_\text{static}} = \left( 1 + \frac{\gamma - 1}{2} \times M^2 \right) ^ \left( \frac{\gamma}{\gamma - 1} \right) $$

where $\gamma$ is the ratio of specific heats for air and $M$ is the Mach number.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/44805)

Comment: edited to include equation. -NN

Comment: OP did not specify stagnation pressure in an engine.

Comment: I'm interested in air hitting the leading edge of an object, like the nose or wing edge. I don't see how to use the equation, tho, because it doesnt have any cross section area or coefficient of drag. Surely the nose of a B747 has more stagnation pressure than the nose of a tiny business jet at the same speed? Likewise for the leading edge of a wing versus the big nose. Without cross section area I don't see how it can be trustworthy. Maybe stagnation pressure is not the right thing after all?

Comment: Also, the edited equation was wrong. Exp means 10 to some power, but what wikipedia says on its page for stagnation pressure, just shows a plain exponent. Edited it.

Comment: @DrZ214 Looks like you’re looking for a drag force then.

Comment: @Koyovis No, that's a force. What i want is a pressure change or density change, but it's obviously highly related to drag. Maybe what I'm thinking of is some kinda cumulative or average pressure change for all the leading air, because it seems stagnation pressure is just measuring pressure at a single point.

Comment: @DrZ214: Stagnation pressure can be found at only one point (the stagnation point, obviously) so there is no area on which it acts. Pressure drops when you move away from the stagnation point, so in reality you will have to integrate with a pressure gradient when calculating drag on the aircraft nose. But stagnation pressure is real: It limits the top speed of blimps to the point where internal pressure equals stagnation pressure, or the blimp's nose will deform.

Comment: @DrZ214 The stagnation pressure is the _maximum_ pressure on a moving blunt object. It's basically the (infinitesimally small) point where air doesn't "know" whether to go left or right around the blunt object, so instead it just compresses. The rest of the air will have a lower pressure (intuitively, because it can convert some of its kinetic energy to sideways kinetic energy instead of potential pressure energy). How quickly the pressure drops away from that point is of course a function of all the factors you mention.

Comment: @DrZ214 So, you’re looking to quantify what happens to the air in front of a body subjected to airflow, correct? How much energy it costs to get out of the way?

Comment: @Koyovis No, I'm looking for a pressure change or density change. Maybe energy can be calculated after that? Or from that? I don't know. If you know some equation that involves energy along with one of those things, go ahead and post it and it should be solvable for the variable I'm interested in. The problem with stagnation pressure equation is it's just at one point. Like Peter Kampf said, you can do it with a pressure gradient and then integrating it. Maybe there's an equation for a pressure gradient, but I don't know it is.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Is there an equation for the pressure gradient across some surface at some airspeed v, and ofc cross section area A? Ideally a body of revolution like a sphere, sears-haack, ellipsoid, etc. I hoped that just the Cd number would be enough, but if it's not that simple, oh well. But if an equation exists for the gradient, then I can definitely integrate it one way or the other. It's okay if there are different equations for different shapes.

Comment: @DrZ214 what you are asking is essentially a solution for the pressure field, which exists in analytical form only for particular cases like potential flow.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer for sub-sonic aircraft is zero. Air does not compress significantly until shock waves start to form.

Pressure changes with speed (as per Bernoulli's principle) but density can be treated as constant.